# linux shell stream redirection to run a list of commands directly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, io-redirection

I have this svn project... to get a list of unadded files (in my case, hundreds):

```
svn status |grep "^?"
```

outputs

```
? somefile.txt
? somefile1.txt
? somefile2.txt
```

I was recently introduced to sed... so now I have a list of commands I want to run

```
svn status | grep "^?"|sed "s/^?/svn add/"
```

outputs

```
svn add somefile.txt
svn add somefile1.txt
svn add somefile2.txt
```

I realize I could just pipe it to a file

```
svn status | grep "^?"|sed "s/^?/svn add/" >out.sh && sh out.sh && rm out.sh
```

But I'd like to avoid writing to a temporary file.  Is there a way I pipe it to some command like this:

```
svn status | grep "^?"|sed "s/^?/svn add/" |some_command_that_runs_each_line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `bash`/`sh`?

```
svn status | grep "^?"|sed "s/^?/svn add/" | bash
```

Comment: Your answer seems really obvious now, but I didn't know bash/sh could accept stream redirection.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the `xargs` command:

```
svn status | grep "^?" | sed "s/^..//" | xargs svn add
```

You can also use substitution:

```
svn add `svn status | grep "^?"` | cut -c 3-`
```

Comment: need to remove the `?`, so add `cut -d " " -f 2-` to the pipeline after the grep

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for i in `svn status | grep "^?"|sed "s/^?/svn add/"`
do
    $i
done
```